# Explanation of the explosion principle

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

The wikipedia page about the principle of explosion "from falsehood, anything" goes like this:

$P$ - assumption
$ \neg P$ - assumption
$ P \vee Q $ - Disjunction
$ Q $ - syllogism

Why would we need the $ \neg P$ then? isn't the "from falsehood, anything".

Isn't saying that "all humans need to breath $\vee$ god exists" says that we can use "god exists" as an argument?

I don't really get this, I would appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Note that "$\vee$" means "**or**," not "**and**." In general, merely having the disjunction $P\vee Q$ doesn't immediately help us get $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do a couple of proofs and then we'll talk about them.

###### Syntactic Proof

$\begin{array}{}
\{1\}&1.&P&\text{Premise}\\
\{2\}&2.&\lnot P&\text{Premise}\\
\{2\}&3.&\lnot P\lor Q&\text{2, $\lor$I}\\
\{2\}&4.&P\to Q&\text{3, $\to$ Def$^1$}\\
\{1,2\}&5.&Q&\text{1, 4, MP}\\
\end{array}$

###### Semantic Proof

$P$ is a premise, so $v(P)=1$ and thus, for an arbitrary wff $Q$, $v(P\lor Q)=1$. $\lnot P$ is a premise, so $v(P)=0$, which means, as $v(P\lor Q)=1$, that $v(Q)=1$. As $Q$ was arbitrary, all wffs are true.

###### Discussion

What's happening in both proofs is we're using [Disjunction Introduction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_introduction) to introduce an arbitrary formula, which we're then able to immediately [detach](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/law-of-detachment). In other words, we're able to prove that an arbitrary formula is a [logical consequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) of contradictory premises. As the formula is arbitrary, we can [generalise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) the result to all applicable formulas, which, in this case, means **all** formulas. More succinctly, from falsehood, anything - ex falso quodlibet.

1: $\to$ [Definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference))

Answer (score 2):

> $P$ - assumption
> $ \neg P$ - assumption
> $ P \vee Q $ - Disjunction
> $ Q $ - syllogism

Since $P$ is true (by assumption 1), then at least one of $P$ and $Q$ is true (line 3).

Since $P$ is false (by assumption 2), by line 3, $Q$ must be true.

> Why would we need the $ \neg P$ then? isn't the "from falsehood, anything".

The conjunction of the two assumptions $P$ and $\neg P$ is a logical falsity (called a contradiction).